# Prevent project creation in gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

As part of our cloud migration, we are deploying all our repositories on github. Due to safety concern, we'd like to keep our local gitlab online for a short period of time in read-only mode. I have archived all projects so no commit can be pushed, but I'm not sure how can I prevent project creation for all users. Ideally, I'm looking for a global flag which will put whole gitlab in RO mode. I'm not sure if it's possible at all. Google didn't yield any result.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html) only Privileges with Master & Owner can create Projects. You could change the Privileges of the Users accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Libin, the problem is that, gitlab requires that at least one member of security group should be an Owner, which I can't change...

Comment: Yes, that is right. You can have one owner, mostly the Admin of the gitlab. And I believe if you are the Admin, you will not go against the rule you set for all to create a project. :)

Comment: Thanks Libin. I'll try